# Trying to get GetPrimaryMACAddress to stop printing verbose

Tags: c, macos, core-foundation

Okay, this one seems to me a bit weird. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I recently implemented code that I found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Introduction/Intro.html) to get the MAC address. The funny thing is that is prints to the console (in addition to the MAC address) something like the following:

```
<CFData 0x317df0 [0xa03e9ee0]>{length = 6, capacity = 6, bytes = 0x001f5bd82fd6}
```

I've tried doing a search through the project/frameworks for 'length =', but nothing has come up.

**How do I get the above to stop printing to the console?**

I'm working in XCode building a mac app using Objective C and C.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is line 185 of `GetPrimaryMACAddress.c`:

```
                CFShow(MACAddressAsCFData); // for display purposes only; [...]
```

Remove this line and that extra output to `stderr` goes away.